# Calculation round off function in Javascript.

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, rounding, multiplication

Let's say 6 is NumberRequiredItems based off some other calculation. I don't want to give out the whole thing, just want to do this round off function

I want to do specific rounding off:

If within 6, round down to multiple of 24 (min of 24), otherwise round up
to multiple of 24.

I get I would do 24*Math.round(NumberRequiredItems), how do I do "Within 6" though?

e.g IF something like 56, go up to 72 items. If 54, go down to 48, etc.

I know it seems a little tricky, but I would love the help. It may even help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use the Modulo operator, `%`, which does a division and returns the remainder to check your condition.

For example: `56 % 24 = 8` and `54 % 24 = 6`

I'd write your rounding function something like this:

```
var roundRequiredItems = function (n) {
  if (n % 24 <= 6) {
    return Math.floor(n / 24) * 24
  } else {
    return Math.ceil(n / 24) * 24
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function amount(NumberRequiredItems) {
    return 24 * Math.floor(NumberRequiredItems / 24) + (NumberRequiredItems % 24 > 6 ? 24 : 0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z7RtG/

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the fact that, in javascript, n+true equals n+1 to solve your problem in a smart way :

```
function foo(n)
{
    return 24*( Math.floor(n/24) + (n%24 > 6));
}
```